# Saving path (not in streets) - Google API

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am trying to write an app where you can save your path in woods (not streets). In order to do that I need to collect data about position (from GPS). Naturally firstly I thought about google maps but I couldn't really find in their API anything about paths which were not on streets. I also didn't find anything on stack.

Any help? Should I collect GPS position once in a second and then simply draw it on Google? Is there any better solution?

@edit1 that app will be on smartphones (firstly iOS and then maybe on android so I am searching for iOS/android API)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i think you need to store the coordinate of position along the path  and draw the path using GMSPolyline.

Eg.

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1,lon1)];
.
.
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latN,lonN)];
GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
```